# How to copy a DVD on Mac

Tags: macos, dvd

Is there any software (preferred free) which allows me to copy a DVD (Disk to Disk copy)?

I have installed Burn, but it does not seem to let me do what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built in disk utility to create and burn images.

There are several guides online about this but this one has pictures!

http://www.thinkmac.net/blog/archives/mac-tips-daily-171-copy-cd-and-dvd-discs.html

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what you are trying to do, [Toast](http://www.roxio.co.uk/) is the Daddy here but it's not free or particularly cheap.

If you are trying to copy a film, you need either [Fairmount](http://www.metakine.com/products/fairmount/) or [Mac the Ripper](http://macupdate.com/info.php/id/14414) (NB MTR is no longer developed and requires Rosetta to run on Snow Leopard) or the commercial [Ripit](http://thelittleappfactory.com/ripit/) (approx $20).  You can also use [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) for direct to device ripping.

There is also [Liquid CD](http://www.maconnect.ch/) another free DVD programme.